# what is the max width of a facebook page?

Tags: facebook, width

i read it was going to be changed to 520px in early 2010, but i keep seeing pages that are new that are the older 760px width - is it safe to build at the wider width still or should we be building at 520px?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a Page page or an app Canvas page? As far as I know, app Canvas pages are staying at 760px, and I think a reduction is very unlikely. The application tabs on Pages (and user profiles) are being reduced to 520px, though, so if your application is going to be displayed there then I'd work to that dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Am I late? lol... yes...

It's now 810px ;)

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like the "max" width is 760px, but the "best" width would probably be what the newest is (as the old width might be dropped at some point)

Answer (score 0):

They are unlikely to mandate reduction in width across all apps; the current max is 760px, so I would use that.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types - Canvas Apps, which live on http://apps.facebook.com/YOUR_APP_NAME) or Page Tab apps which reside on a page like this one [Starbucks](http://www.facebook.com/Starbucks/app_142063194423).

Canvas width and height can be set as fluid or fixeed. Fluid means it will fill the whole page, so you have no width restriction. Fixed width is set at 760px.

Tab apps used to be 520px, but now you have the option of 810px as well - you can set this in the developer app.